# numpy combine arrays with index ordering

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to combine multiple numpy arrays by the order of the index. Here is what I mean: Suppose I have two numpy arrays like

```py
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [-5, -6, -7, -8]
```

How can I combine these arrays such that the output is

```py
c = np.combination_function((a,b))
>>> c = [0 -5, 1, -6, 2, -7, 3, -8]
```

`concatenate` and `append` will place `a` and `b` "next" to each other, which is not quite what I want.

Numpy's `repeat` and `tile` functions serve as an analogy here. For example

```py
np.repeat([3, 4, 2], 2)
>>> [3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2] # two 3's, then two 4's, then two 2's. This is what I want
np.tile([3, 4, 2], 2)
>>> [3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2] # [3,4,2] twice. This is not what I want
```

`tile` is to `concatenate` as `repeat` is to `???`

**A solution:**

I've been able to accomplish this with

```py
c = np.stack((a,b)).flatten('F')
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is pretty good. You can speed it up a bit by doing the stacking already in FORTRAN order:

```
timeit(lambda:np.stack([a,b]).flatten("F"))
# 11.13118030806072
timeit(lambda:np.array([a,b],order="F").ravel(order="K"))
# 3.0580440941266716
```